# FOSUserBundle : UserInterface & inheritance mapping

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

How to create user with FOSUserBundle::UserInterface?
Then how to add inheritance mapping to my user class?

I've try it now a wek ago but not working... Error saying that my class shoulb be `abstract`, then docrine warn when executing `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Answer (score 0):

Your entity should extend FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as write in documentation:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#a-doctrine-orm-user-class

Comment: Thanks for the link! Now I need to `extend` the class like `SuperAdminitrator extends \My\Bundle\User` and `Adminitrator extends \My\Bundle\User`